# How can I achieve a single mySQL row answer?

Tags: mysql

How can I achieve a single mySQL row answer?

I have two tables given:

Table Flats

```
idFlat INT(11)
Street VARCHAR(45)
```

Table Tenants

```
id Tenant INT(11)
Flats_idFlat INT(11)
Surname VARCHAR(45)
Firstname VARCHAR(45)
```

My query

```
SELECT
    Flats.idFlat,
    Flats.Street,
    Tenants.Surname,
    Tenants.Firstname
FROM
    Flats
        LEFT JOIN
    Tenants ON Flats.idFlat = Tenants.Flats_idFlat
WHERE
    Tenants.Flats_idFlat IS NOT NULL
```

turns out with the following result because John and Peggy are living in the same flat:

```
idFlat    Street        Surname        Firstname
1          Taft Ave     John               Miller
1          Taft Ave     Peggy             Ballot
```

I’m looking for a result like this:

```
idFlat    Street        Surname        Firstname
1           Taft Ave    John/Peggy    Miller/Ballot
```

I tried some CONCAT_WS queries like

```
CONCAT_WS(‘/', Tenants.Surname, Tenants.Firstname) AS Tenants
```

but it always results in multiple output of the flat.

Comment: Try group_concat [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat]

Comment: This throws an error: Error Code: 1140. In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'Tenants.Flats_idFlat'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Note that Peggy and John are more commonly firstnames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `GROUP_CONCAT` with a custom ordering and separator:

```
SELECT
    f.idFlat,
    f.Street,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.Surname   ORDER BY t.Surname SEPARATOR '/') AS Surname,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.Firstname ORDER BY t.Surname SEPARATOR '/') AS Firstname
FROM Flats f
INNER JOIN Tenants t
    ON f.idFlat = t.Flats_idFlat
GROUP BY
    f.idFlat,
    f.Street
```

Note that your current left join probably can be reduced to an inner join given the logic in the where clause.

Comment: Hurray! Works perfect. Thank you very much. You made my day.